# Name of this matrix product?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices

Suppose $A$ and $B$ have columns as follows,
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & \dots & a_n
\end{bmatrix},$$
$$B = \begin{bmatrix}
b_1 & b_2 & \dots & b_n
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Is there any name for the following matrix "product", or simple way of expressing in terms of standard matrix operations:
$$A \times B := \begin{bmatrix}
a_1 b_1^T & a_2 b_1^T & \dots & a_n b_1^T \\
a_1 b_2^T & a_2 b_2^T & \dots & a_n b_2^T \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_1 b_n^T & a_2 b_n^T & \dots & a_n b_n^T
\end{bmatrix}?$$

---

It is almost like the product of the [vectorizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29),
$$\mathrm{vec}(B)\mathrm{vec}(A)^T = \begin{bmatrix}
b_1 a_1^T & b_1 a_2^T & \dots & b_1 a_n^T \\
b_2 a_1^T & b_2 a_2^T & \dots & b_2 a_n^T \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
b_n a_1^T & b_n a_2^T & \dots & b_n a_n^T
\end{bmatrix}$$
except every sub block is individually transposed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm answering my own question. It is related to the answers given by both AJMansfield and Tony J., but slightly different, needing the inclusion of a vectorization transpose reordering operator, which is more involved than a simple transpose.

Long story short, the answer is that the desired matrix is given by,
$$(B^T \otimes A)P,$$

where $\otimes$ is the Kronecker (outer) product, and $P$ is the [commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix): a permutation matrix that converts $\mathrm{vec}(X^T)$ into $\mathrm{vec}(X)$.

**Reframe problem in terms of [vectorizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29) matrix equation**

The matrix needed, $(A \times B)$, is the matrix satisfying the following vectorized matrix equation,
$$(A \times B)\mathrm{vec}(X) = \mathrm{vec}(AX^TB).$$

To see this, let the columns of $A,X,B$ be denoted $a_i,x_i,b_i$ respectively and compute,
$$\mathrm{vec}(AX^TB) = \begin{bmatrix}
AX^T b_1 \\
AX^T b_2 \\
\vdots \\
AX^T b_n
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
A \begin{bmatrix}
x_1^Tb_1 \\
x_2^T b_1 \\
\vdots \\
x_n^T b_1
\end{bmatrix} \\
A \begin{bmatrix}
x_1^Tb_2 \\
x_2^T b_2 \\
\vdots \\
x_n^T b_2
\end{bmatrix} \\
\vdots
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\sum_i a_i x_i^T b_1 \\
\sum_i a_i x_i^T b_2 \\
\vdots \\
\sum_i a_i x_i^T b_n
\end{bmatrix}= \\ \begin{bmatrix}
\sum_i a_i b_1^T x_i \\
\sum_i a_i b_2^T x_i \\
\vdots \\
\sum_i a_i b_n^T x_i
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 b_1^T & a_2 b_1^T & \dots & a_n b_1^T \\
a_1 b_2^T & a_2 b_2^T & \dots & a_n b_2^T \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_1 b_n^T & a_2 b_n^T & \dots & a_n b_n^T
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
\vdots \\
x_n
\end{bmatrix} = (A \times B)\mathrm{vec}(X).$$

The matrix expression $\mathrm{vec}(AX^TB)$ is actually where the original question came from before I asked it.

**Expressing matrix product in terms of Kronecker product and commutation matrix**

Using the vectorized matrix expression interpretation of the matrix, and recalling the [relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Matrix_equations) between the outer (kronecker) product and vectorization yields,
$$\mathrm{vec}(AX^TB) = (B^T \otimes A)\mathrm{vec}(X^T).$$
This is almost what we want, except we have $X^T$ within the vectorization instead of $X$. Introducing the commutation matrix $P$ (transpose reordering matrix) defined such that
$$\boxed{P\mathrm{vec}(X) := \mathrm{vec}(X^T)},$$
we have
\begin{align}
(A \times B)\mathrm{vec}(X) =& \mathrm{vec}(AX^TB) \\
=& (B^T \otimes A)\mathrm{vec}(X^T) \\
=& (B^T \otimes A)P\mathrm{vec}(X),
\end{align}
and so
$$\boxed{(A \times B) = (B^T \otimes A)P}.$$

**Commutation matrix (more details)**

The commutation matrix $P$ is uniquely defined by the above relation, but it also has a simple construction as follows. Let $Y$ be the matrix of the same size as $X$, but with value $k$ at the $k$'th linear index - $\mathrm{vec}(Y) = (1,2,3,4,5,6,\dots,nm)^T$. For example in the 4-by-5 case we have,
$$Y = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 5 & 9  & 13 & 17 \\
2 & 6 & 10 & 14 & 18\\
3 & 7 & 11 & 15 & 19\\
4 & 8 & 12 & 16 & 20
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Then $P$ is the permutation matrix where the $1$ in the $i$'th row is in the column given by the $i'th$ entry of $\mathrm{vec}(Y^T)$. Ie,
$$P_{ij} = \begin{cases}
1, \quad j \mathrm{~is~the~}i'th\mathrm{~entry~of~}\mathrm{vec}(Y^T), \\
0, \quad \mathrm{else}
\end{cases}$$
In picture form, it looks like this:
[image: Commutation operator]

**Matlab code**

The following code generates the commutation matrix. I release it to the public domain.

```
function P = vecpermute(n,m)
%Gives the permutation matrix to take the vectorization of a matrix to the
% vectorization of it's transpose. Ie, P*vec(X) = vec(X^T).
    Y = zeros(n,m);
    for k=1:n*m
        Y(k) = k;
    end
    YT = Y';
    P = sparse(Y(:),YT(:),ones(length(Y(:)),1), n*m, n*m);
end
```

**Python code**

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sps

def perfect_shuffle_matrix(n,m):
    # S*vec(X) = vec(X^T), where X is n-by-m
    Y = np.arange(n*m).reshape((n,m))
    ii = Y.reshape(-1)
    jj = Y.T.reshape(-1)
    vv = np.ones(len(ii))
    S = sps.coo_matrix((vv,(ii,jj)), shape=(n*m, n*m)).tocsr()
    return S

# Test perfect_shuffle_matrix:
X = np.random.randn(41,13)
S = perfect_shuffle_matrix(*X.shape)
shuffle_err = np.linalg.norm(S*X.reshape(-1) - X.T.reshape(-1))
print('shuffle_err=', shuffle_err)
```

Comment: This permutation matrix has in fact a name : "commutation matrix" (given in the answer by Yaroslav Bulatov)

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for pointing this out. I edited the answer to use the phrase "commutation matrix", and added a link to the wikipedia article about it.

Comment: The Commutation Matrix can be calculated in one line of _Julia_  by reordering the columns of a _sparse_ identity matrix
$$\tt{
P \;=\; sparse(1*I,m*n,m*n)[\,vec(reshape(collect(1\!:\!m*n),m,n)'), :\,]
}$$

Answer (score 2):

BTW, in Mathematica you can do the following to find commutation matrix

```
(* column vectorize, following Magnus, 1999 *)

vec[W_] := Transpose@{Flatten@Transpose[W]};

(* Commutation matrix m,n *)
Kmat[m_, n_] := Module[{x},
  X = Array[x, {m, n}];
  before = Flatten@vectorize@X;
  after = Flatten@vectorize@Transpose[X];
  positions = 
   MapIndexed[{First@#2, First@Flatten@Position[before, #]} &, 
    after];
  matrix = SparseArray[# -> 1 & /@ positions]
  ];

On[Assert];
X = Array[x, {4, 3}];
Assert[Kmat[4, 3].vec[X] == vec[X\[Transpose]]];
Y = Array[x, {11, 6}];
Assert[Kmat[11, 6].vec[Y] == vec[Y\[Transpose]]];
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand your question but $({\rm vec}(A){\rm vec}(B)^T)^T$` would look exactly like your operation $A \times B$.

Comment: If element multiplication is not commutative then they are __not__ the same.

Comment: oh yes, my bad. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This looks like its the [transpose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) of the [outer product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#The_inner_and_outer_products): $(A\otimes B)^T$.

Comment: I thought this too, but it's not. Look at the $a_i$ indices as you go down a single column - in the outer product they change, whereas in the product I'm interested in, they stay the same.

Comment: Not the same with the transpose either - when you take the transpose the order of the products in each block switches so that $b$ is before $a$.

Comment: @NickAlger Really? Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: Well just think of the case where the matrix is a single block. Then it comes down to the normal rules of transposes $(ab)^T = b^Ta^T$. See also, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246289/transpose-of-block-matrix